# What is the version number when installing zend framework 3 by composer

Tags: zend-framework, installation, zend-framework3

I installed ZF3 by composer but don't understand installed version number of Zend. When skeleton download and viewing the output at browser it says 3.xx.xx-dev.

Is there development release installed (I don't want this development release, I want stable release)? OR the version displaying the version of skeleton project?

I installed zend by following simple composer command (which is suggested by official zend site)

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework
```

Is there any way to tell composer to install only stable version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the command:

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework
```

You can check composer.json file and see the version:

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

So by default it will be **at least 3.0 stable**. But...

There is no ZF version 3, since the whole framework is separate in small composer packages. Every package has it's own scope and version.

Repository on github [zendframework/zendframework](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework) contains composer.json file with other dependencies, where you can check version of every component.

https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/blob/master/composer.json